# video play on IE11 gives Unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: html, reactjs

Hi,

```
                <video poster={this.props.videoPosterSrc} autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
                    <source src={this.props.videoMp4Src} type="video/mp4" />
                    <source src={this.props.videoWebmSrc} type="video/webm />  
                </video>
```

When the code loads and runs .play() it gives the next error:

```
Unexpected call to method or property access.
```

This happens on IE11 & IE12(EDGE)

Comment: Can you provide your failed code, pls? cause seems like everything is ok, except unclosed double quote.

Comment: Hi @Alon, did you get any clue why it is not working?